# PromiseKit `Result.. is unused warning` in a chained sequence with a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, promisekit

I have this annoying warning and I'm not able to get rid of it.
Let's say that I have a promise that sends a command to a bluetooth le device, to do a procedure I need to send these commands synchronously.
So what you can do in PromiseKit 6 is create a for loop and append each command using a then to the previous promise. The issue with that approach is that the compiler trigger a warning about an `Result of call to 'then(on:flags:_:)' is unused`, is like is missing the `catch`. I'm aware that I can use a `cauterize()` , but in this case I guess I will lost errors thrown while executing each promise. A `when` is not viable because it will execute concurrently while I need synchronously.
Here a small sample used with strings, in my real application they are NOT string.

```
 static func promise_startProcedure(with commands: [String]) -> Promise<Void> {
        let promise = Promise()
        for command in commands {
            promise.then { //<-- WARNING SHOW HERE
                Promise.value(command)
            }
        }
        return promise
    }
```

Is there a way to get rid of this warning?

[UPDATE]
I did a mistake, the answer was not correct bu pointed me to the right direction.

```
static func promise_startProcedure(with commands: [String]) -> Promise<Void> {
            var promise = Promise()
            for command in commands {
                promise = promise.then { 
                    Promise.value(command)
                }
            }
            return promise
        }
```

Comment: I don't see any usefulness of the promises.

Comment: @Kamran of course, as I said this is just a little example, this procedure is chained with other promises and at the end there is a `catch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. I just added `Underscore` to suppress the warning and did not get that warning.

```swift
static func promise_startProcedure(with commands: [String]) -> Promise<Void> {
    let promise = Promise()
    for command in commands {
        _ = promise.then {
            Promise.value(command)
        }
    }
    return promise
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `@discardableResult` to the declaration of the method. [From the docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html):

> For example, the discardableResult attribute on a function declaration
>   indicates that, although the function returns a value, the compiler
>   shouldn’t generate a warning if the return value is unused.

Comment: It won't work, the warning is shown here `promise.then {` but thanks for pointing it, I will edit the question